# How to highlight the zoomed in bar and know the details of that bar in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am able to create the overview details bar graph and zoomed-in nicely when I select the range in the bottom graph. But I am having difficulty to highlight the bars in the zoomed-in graph and also know what bars have been selected.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "actions": false,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      { "created": 1595053277243 },
      { "created": 1595053277244 },
      { "created": 1595055277243 },
      { "created": 1594880606860 },
      { "created": 1594880604261 }
    ]
  },
  "vconcat": [{
        "width": 1500,
        "height": 300,
        "selection": {
          "highlight": {"type": "single", "empty": "none", "on": "mouseover"},
          "select": {"type": "multi"}
        },
        "mark": {
          "type": "bar",
          "fill": "#4C78A8",
          "stroke": "black",
          "cursor": "pointer"
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "created",
            "type": "temporal",
            "scale": {"domain": {"selection": "brush"}},
            "axis": {"title": ""},
            "timeUnit": "utcyearmonthdatehoursminutes",
            "update": {
              "fillOpacity": {
                "condition": {"selection": "select", "value": 1},
                "value": 0.3
              },
              "strokeWidth": {
                "condition": [
                  {
                    "test": {
                      "and": [
                        {"selection": "select"},
                        "length(data(\"select_store\"))"
                      ]
                    },
                    "value": 2
                  },
                  {"selection": "highlight", "value": 1}
                ],
                "value": 0
              }
            }
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "created",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "aggregate": "count"
          }
        },
        "config": {
          "scale": {
            "bandPaddingInner": 0.2
          }
        }
      }, {
        "width": 1500,
        "height": 100,
        "padding": 10,
        "mark": "bar",
        "selection": {
          "brush": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"]}
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "created",
            "type": "temporal",
            "timeUnit": "utcyearmonthdatehours"
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "created",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "aggregate": "count"
          }
        }
      }]
}
```

I tried to put the fill-opacity and stroke-width in encoding but doesn't seem to work. I also tried to patch the compiled vega in vega-embed to listen to the bar click event but it doesn't listen to the top (zoomed in) graph.

[Example of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgxO5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vega-Lite encodings have no `update` property. You can specify the features directly in the encoding mapping:

```
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "created",
          "type": "temporal",
          "scale": {"domain": {"selection": "brush"}},
          "axis": {"title": ""},
          "timeUnit": "utcyearmonthdatehoursminutes"
        },
        "fillOpacity": {
          "condition": {"selection": "select", "value": 1},
          "value": 0.3
        },
        "strokeWidth": {
          "condition": [
            {
              "test": {
                "and": [
                  {"selection": "select"},
                  "length(data(\"select_store\"))"
                ]
              },
              "value": 2
            },
            {"selection": "highlight", "value": 1}
          ],
          "value": 0
        },
        "y": {"field": "created", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "count"}
      }
```

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQSKJnayIaAGZJBEOEoAmSTClShiuhnE2oA2qCgAnOCbiG0ARgCsATm8ADN4AzABMAOzhoWLBAL4Kji5uHqg+-kFhkdFi8YmumO5efoHe3hFRMbkgzvmFqX5iAByNAQBsbY3tVTXJRb5NLe1ioa2esQC68SDEUHJQJmgOIADuNIb0RQEBSvA0ZFhowVtK+oJwqupooDB7MML7mFcgmACeOHBoIBA0smRniiBEDhXp9ZHIPko5J8EGwGPo2KQnCApqdzo9zM83h90AgGII1MipsgnABrJ6vd6fJhIJFKLQ0QSCT4AYjEAGFwo0AIKNAEQTBONgk7EgJiCFRkpRQBhOGRI9A4Ng-ApIqZwWSzQw-MhPAAeT3pcEEKWqSQKHiUFJFBQQiqcuj583+GMMbGQPyeqIuUPQTCccJghKUSF1NFsoDUmGdIGRlpoCDgAFVZHRPgxMFAXq4nDDZPRjAUYLDZQgfumbLGQPTGQB5HAqOgvJ6zWRatQ+0Be9vydBdgGWQTWLxTAdD1ABShxE4CoVwADqaw2GJbbcu9gjNnRoCQrcWnaNaLXXwPqkrZ1+9AAFAWkJeADrHs6qAD6-LYLgfAEpPyBJkpR9ioRVF2R43Ps9wHP+VjYmM4xQYO2IBFMTYYoaxqfD05oAlanwAI4MDukYmDQpAAkgZBkC4FAFBhsJ5oSVSrOsgb1McGBwLc6KeGxxJkr6NJ8ie3ZPH6AbklinzKnATgDgC6qatqth2CA+qTGqGpsFqvx6gaNBGiamGFJaEnoDadoOnGCbJqm6Dppm2a5vmbhFjKmjIbp+kYWaRmYpS6D4YRdDEaRwYUVRbi0Qw9GxDFcHVHI9I6hi0C6NioDUq2AAKSCGFpZAAJKyLI0loBOQExUAA)

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. May I also know how to access the select_store to see all the selected bars, if I have type as multi in highlight? Right now the patch method is only capturing the mousedown event